# create floating window with control user for the text box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to open the following form after pressing the Enter key in textbox...
I want to create such a floating window....>>>I have trouble making such a floating window for the text box

[image 1 for description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYO5.png)

[image 2 is gift for description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIbSH.gif)

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question, or showed any attempt to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Please review the [tour] and [ask] pages and try again.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your itens in a [panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=net-5.0) and make it visible or invisible when press Enter...

And the code to do that:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then mypanel.visible = Not mypanel.visible 
End Sub
```

To make it float, you've to use this [code](https://www.programmerall.com/article/43752014782/):

```
Private IsPanelBeingDragged As Boolean = False
Private MouseDownX As Integer
Private MouseDownY As Integer

Private Sub MyPanel_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mytextbox.MouseDown

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        IsPanelBeingDragged = True
        MouseDownX = e.X
        MouseDownY = e.Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyPanel_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mytextbox.MouseUp

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        IsPanelBeingDragged = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyPanel_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mytextbox.MouseMove

    If IsPanelBeingDragged Then
        Dim temp As System.Drawing.Point = New System.Drawing.Point()

        temp.X = mypanel.Location.X + (e.X - MouseDownX)
        temp.Y = mypanel.Location.Y + (e.Y - MouseDownY)
        mypanel.Location = temp
        temp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ---Thank you for your answer, but I have a problem making such a floating window

Comment: ---I want such a floating window for the text box    https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIbSH.gif

Comment: Just changes the "Handles mypanel.MouseMove" to "Handles mytextbox.MouseMove" @mostafabarzegar